# Python : dll function return void *

Tags: python, dll

I'm new to Python and i'm trying to deal with an custom dll.  Here's my problem.

I'm able to load the dll with ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary() function

The first call I do with the dll is a function that should return an void * to an object.  Here's the function :

```
void * Create(void)
{
    if ( !gInitCalled )
    {
    Init();
    }

    return new Device;
}
```

What should be the code to keep the pointer to Device for future use?  Something like this?

```
MyDevice = ctypes.c_void_p(Mydll.Create())
```

After the call, MyDevice has the value c_void_p(177734563).  Is it correct?  I guess it is the address of the Device object.

Next question : How should I use it? Is it correct like this if the function needs a void* for input?

```
success = Mydll.Connect(MyDevice)
```

This function from the dll is returning an error saying invalid argument.  This is raised if the void * is null.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: My `ctypes` is a bit rusty, but I _think_ you need to tell Python the [argtypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes) of the `Connect` function. Otherwise, it just sees the `MyDevice` arg as an integer.

Comment: The related question [Basic Python questions about calling functions from a loaded DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651503/basic-python-questions-about-calling-functions-from-a-loaded-dll) looks helpful, especially if you're doing this on Windows.

Comment: Thanks PM 2Ring for the info.  Finally it works has I expected it.  The call to the function needed one more arguments.  Thanks again for your support.